# jquery ajax json parseerror valid json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

Hi im having parseerror ajax call using jquery - servlet. im at lost. oh please what to do.
and data from servlet is a valid json `{"success":true,"SelectPartid":{"partidAll":"DA04321;"}}`

if i discard the `dataType: 'json',`this work fine. but then i cant use this code

`if (data.success) {
alert("SUCCESS!!");
//alert("success" + data.SelectPartid.partidAll);
}`

so, the ajax,please advise

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    dataString = "Optionselected=" + $("#select1 option:selected").text();
    alert("dataString : " + dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'SelectAjx',
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        context: this,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("SUCCESS!!");
                //alert("success" + data.SelectPartid.partidAll);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            //alert('[jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [textStatus:' + textStatus + '], [thrownError:' + errorThrown + '])');
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Quick observation. `"DA04321;"` is that `;` *definitely* inside the double quotes?

Comment: Are you sure the response looks like the JSON you showed us?

Comment: i hve test it at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ .that is a valid json

Comment: @RGraham yes it is inside the double quotes

Comment: @RGraham that ; serves as delimiter when there are more than one result.

Comment: Appear to work ok at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7w3av/ .

Comment: @guest271314 yes that definitely work ok,im using netbeans. does it have anything to do that would cause the parseerror?

Comment: If possible, can post error message ? Tried full path at `url` ?

Comment: i didnt know what u means by `url` but the error message is

Comment: [textStatus:parseerror][thrownError: SyntaxError:Syntax error]

Comment: `application/json` this solve it cant believe i waste 2 hours because of this line. the ajax doesnt cause the error..its in the servlet.

this is the line

`response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`

what i just dd is change it to 

`response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");`

and there the error swooshd away.thank god

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application/json` this solve it cant believe i waste 2 hours because of this line. the ajax doesnt cause the error..its in the servlet.

this is the line

`response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");`

what i just dd is change it to

`response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");`

and there the error swooshd away.thank god

*-copy from my last comment, im sure this gonna be useful to someone.*